# Blackberry ListField Selection Help (not getSelectedIndex() Related)

Tags: blackberry, java-me, listfield

I have a list field that I am using to display a list of categories, these categories have sub categories. I need to navigate the top level categories using the ListField. So when user selects Category 1 I can load a list of Sub Categories.

Problem is I know getSelectedIndex() will tell me the index of the current selected category, but that is of no help because I need to get the title or better the DB ID of the category, so I can have the webserver serve up the sub categories.

The closest I can figure is using `rows.elementAt(Index).toString();` to tell give me the current row, but I have been unable to find examples on how to use it properly.

So if any one has a snip of code showing how to get the contents of a listField row, it would be appreciated.

screen shot of what I am talking about:
[image: BlackBerry Storm screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I usually create a vector that I use to build the ListField from. Then when a row is selected I simply access the vector at the same index as the selection.

Comment: Thanks that whats I did, was able to then store the cat_id & parent_id to send over the webserver.